# Dead Raspberry Pi, Rev 1.4, please help me identify model of the chip

Tags: pi-4, hardware, power-management

[image: Chip I am missing]

Hi! I am trying to fix shorted out Raspberry Pi 4B and I identified this chip as bad (Running extremely hot while Raspberry looks dead).
The chip itself is scratched and protected from reading model number.
I can't replace it if I do not know manufacturer, model, etc.

Please, I can't find any documentation online for it. Please help me.

Comment: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=326251

Comment: In case the duplicate isn't clear, the fact that those inductors get hot does not mean they are the problem, and as per the forum thread (link in last comment), replacing the PMIC (big square with no markings, just above the inductors) is not feasible: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=314996